# Dynamics CRM security role privileges on Email entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, security-roles

I have noticed that a CRM user can see all emails of people belonging to his same business unit. Where does this behavior come from? I didn't find the Email entity in the Security roles privileges definition, that looks very strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email is an activity, so this share the same privilege set as other activities like Task, Appointment, Fax, etc.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes one  forgets even so basic things, thank you ;)

Comment: @Sean it happens, and can happen to anyone.. lol. you can upvote/accept the answer to close the question